# Does .ajaxComplete fire before or after the success callback?

Tags: jquery, ajax

If after, is there a way to tell if the call succeeded or failed?

If before, is there a way to run a function after the success function runs (on every call)?

Comment: Is there a specific use case here?

Answer (score 10):

You can control your ajax request in multiple situations:

```
$.ajax({
    // some option
    beforeSend: function () {
        // number 1
    },
    success: function () {
        // number 2
    },
    error: function () {
        // number 2
    },
    complete: function () {
        // number 3
    }
});
```

Based on the request, two possible situation will occur.

---

### SUCCESS

When the request succeeds. In this situation, the order of callbacks will be:

```
[1] beforeSend
[2] success
[3] complete
```

---

### ERROR

When the request fails. In this situation, the order of callbacks will be:

```
[1] beforeSend
[2] error
[3] complete
```

Comment: Although this is a very old answer, it does not address the question - When is ajaxComplete() fired in relation to $.ajax({ success: function(){...}});

Answer (score 1):

> **complete**
>
> A function
> to be called when the request finishes (after success and error
> callbacks are executed).

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/)

It is for `$.ajax` but it is true for `$.ajaxComplete` as well.

Comment: But, `ajaxComplete` is calling before success and error callbacks are executed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you tried but the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) says:

Description: Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete.

The [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) event has its own success and fail settings